# Why NSURL query doesn´t work

Tags: xcode, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I hope someone can help me because I'm frustrating.

I can´t figure out why if I execute :

fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myweb.com/my.pdf"];

then I can display the file correctly in a QLpreviewController

but If I execute

fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myweb.com/download.php?Id=1"]; // is a pdf file

then the file is displayed with encoded characters

Please, anyone can help me ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is that the `QLPreviewController` is identifying the content type from the filename (.pdf) in the first example, but does not have that information in the second example.

If you're using PHP you can probably use a server-side rewrite to make a URL that ends in .pdf (and include the argument in the filename).